# Function created with compilation error in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When I compile the below code I am getting a error message "**Function created with compilation errors**"

```
create or replace function find_port(ip_ID in int) RETURN int
is
    t_count number;
    count varchar;
begin
    select is_rail into count from table where id = ip_ID;

    case 
        when count ='True' then t_count:=1;
        when count ='False' then t_count:=0;
    end case;
end;
/
```

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  *"It's code and you tried to compile it - it's not a query and you didn't execute it."* - classic WR :)

Comment: Thanks :) My boss mixes this stuff up all the time and it drives me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

> i am getting a error message "Function created with compilation errors"

So the question you should be asking is, "how do I get a list of compilation errors for my PL/SQL code?"

Other people have told you how to fix the current errors in your code, but the more important skill is that you find out how to diagnose your code for yourself.

Oracle is a database, and it stores metadata in a set of special views called the data dictionary. These views include views for compilation errors. This query will work in any SQL environments:

```
select name, type, line, text -- or just *, obvs
from user_errors ue
order by ue.name, ue.type, ue.sequence;
```

There are also ALL_ERRORS and DBA_ERRORS views. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2237BC4D-F34A-48C5-8181-85426077E65B.htm#REFRN20065).

In SQL*Plus you can run `sho err` (short for `show errors`). IDEs like PL/SQL Developer or Oracle SQL Developer will show compilation errors automatically.

Once you know how to get the text of the errors you need to know that `LINE` will tell you the line where the error is raised. Although with certain classes of error (such as missing commas or unmatched brackets) the indicated line may not be the line where the actual error resides. Unfortunately there is still a need for interpretation and understanding, which requires experience.

Answer (score 1):

`count` is a SQL function and thus not a better choice to be used as a PL/SQL variable. The `CASE` block can be used within the select statement.

Furthermore, your function does not `RETURN` any value.

```
 create or replace function find_port(ip_ID in int) RETURN int
  is
      t_count number;
  begin
      select case 
         when is_rail = 'True' then  1
         when is_rail = 'False' then 0
         end  into t_count from yourtable where id=ip_ID;
      RETURN t_count;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, COUNT *can* be used as a PL/SQL variable:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return int is
  2    count number;
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into count from dual;
  5    return 2;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         2

SQL>
```

However, you can't *return* it:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return int is
  2    count number;
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into count from dual;
  5    return count;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for FUNCTION F_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/10     PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a
         SQL statement only

SQL>
```

Here, @priya, you can see how to help yourself - SHOW ERR will tell you what's wrong with your code.

Apart from that, CASE statement you used was invalidly written; should have been similar to this:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return int is
  2    l_count number;
  3    t_count number;
  4  begin
  5    select 1 into l_count from dual;
  6
  7    t_count := case when l_count = 1 then 1
  8                    when l_count = 2 then 2
  9               end;
 10
 11    return t_count;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

    F_TEST
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: *"Actually, COUNT can be used as a PL/SQL variable:"* Does because we can doesn't mean me should. It's difficult enough to write good programs which can be understood our colleagues who have to work with our code, why make it harder for them by unnecessarily using Oracle keywords to name our variables?

Comment: Also, other than its invalid use of `count` keyword the OP's CASE statement is perfectly fine in PL/SQL as is. So I'm not sure why you suggested it needed to be rewritten. This is on its way to being a half-decent answer but contains too much which is unhelpful to worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Whoa, hold your horses! :) I was referring to Kaushik Nayak's words, who said that COUNT *IS NOT ALLOWED* (which has now been edited) well, it *IS* allowed. I never said that you SHOULD do it. As of OP's CASE statement: are you sure it is correctly written? I'm quite sure that it is not (at least not on my Oracle 11gR2). I'd like to demonstrate it, but comment won't allow me (not enough space), and it would be inappropriate to post another answer, wouldn't it? So ... I don't know what to.

Comment: Your response doesn't make it clear that you are referencing a different answer not the OP's question. SO is a Q&A site, the ideal thread is a good question and *one* answer (preferably an accepted one). Thus each answer must be self-contained and correct. Your note on `count` as a variable name properly belongs as a comment on **that** post, not as the opening to your answer.

Comment: Your answer could include a demonstration of improved `case` syntax if you want it to. I'd personally prefer the more compact `case somevar when...` form, but the OP's version seems to be one of the few bits that's actually valid.

Comment: @Littlefoot : A comment on my answer about your concern and i wouldn't have minded. I would have been willing to accept my mistakes in my choice of words such as "not allowed". However, the way this answer began, it seemed the only target was to disparage and criticize another answer. I strongly believe that our aim should be to contribute to the knowledge-base and the reader/answer-seeker must decide on the legitimacy of an answer. Let us strive for the best keeping this in mind.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm here for a few days and I managed to do quite a few stupidities ("not following the rules"). When in Rome, act like a Roman. I'll try, at least. I apologize if my post made you think that I think that your answer was "stupid". Nope, it was just wrong, literally. COUNT can be a variable name. I agree that anyone should avoid it; the fact that you can do it doesn't mean that you shoud do it. I can poke my eye with a sharp pencil, but I'm trying not to do it. Anyway: I'm OK and hope you all are fine too. Looking forward to future disagreements! :)

Comment: Hello, @William, nice to see you too! We've known each other for ... what, at least 12 years. Gosh, time does go by, doesn't it?

Comment: One more thing, everyone: I sincerely apologize & admit - I was terribly wrong about the CASE statement. As I said, I was 100% sure that it can't be correct. Now I rewrote it, carefully, and - yes, it compiles. Sorry again.